# AWS CLI not working because of unsupported Python version

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, macos, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm trying to download the AWS CLI tools onto my mac. The error message is pretty clear `Unsupported Python version detected: Python 2.7 To continue using this installer you must use Python 3.6 or later.` The issue I'm having is that aliasing `python` to `python3` isn't working. For some reason, after aliasing, the installer still references `Python 2.7`.

After aliasing through the cli didn't work for installing AWS CLI, I added `alias python=python3` to my `.zshrc` file. Running `python --version` returns `Python 3.9.6`. Running the AWS installer still references the older version of python.

I'm hesitant to completely override the older version, because I've read from multiple sources that the default python on OS X should not be touched.

Can someone explain how I can reference the newer version of python when installing the AWS CLI tools?

Comment: Agreed with you that default python should not be touched. but for just sake of information : python3 is now python, python2 has been stopped last year in favour of python3 as it was causing too much caos in head for handling modules based on different version. For your answer please do check your PYTHONPATH. it will fix this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to install the old awscli? The new one uses a pkg install https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-mac.html

Comment: Did you install [awscli v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html)? Also see [about awscli versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/welcome-versions.html).

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to download an old version of the awscli. After downloading the newest version I ran into some issues with the credentials file. Upon updating the credentials file and adding a config file in the `.aws` directory, everything worked as expected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @kylejw2 Feel free to create an Answer for your own Question to help Future readers.

Answer (score 10):

while installation, choosing python3 worked well for me. Choose the "To install the AWS CLI version using the bundled installer" from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-macos.html

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Replace `/usr/local/bin/python3` with the path to your python binary with `version >= 3.6`.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was trying to download an old version of the awscli. After downloading the newest version I ran into some issues with the credentials file. Upon updating the credentials file **and** adding a config file in the `.aws` directory, everything worked as expected.